# How to clear selection/unselect rows on datagridview while on FullRowSelect

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagridview

So I actually have a problem where if you select a row from the dgv then you decide to unselect it. The dgv is on FullRowSelect but what I want is that how do you actually unselect rows from dgv just by clicking the selected rows?

I actually tried to do this code with another dgv.

```
Private Sub DGV_ICT11_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DGV_ICT11.Click
    If DGV_ICT11.SelectedRows.Count = 1 Then
        DGV_ICT12.ClearSelection()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub DGV_ICT12_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DGV_ICT12.Click
    If DGV_ICT12.SelectedRows.Count = 1 Then
        DGV_ICT11.ClearSelection()
    End If
End Sub
```

Although they'll just have an alternation of unselecting rows.

Comment: A `DataGridView` works much like everything else in Windows that supports multiple selections. Clicking a row will select that row and unselect every other row. Ctrl+clicking a row will toggle its selection state without affecting any other row. As such, you unselect rows by Ctrl+clicking them. That will work on the clicked row regardless of how many rows are selected. There's no code required.

Comment: If your issue is keeping the selections in two grids synced then you can simply handle the `SelectionChanged` of each grid and then manually sync them.

Comment: how about storing the current index of datagrid in variable? then compare whenever user click. `if variable = grid.rowIndex then clear selection and set variable into -1 else just reassign the variable to new rowindex`